# How to make object move continously without stopping(unity2d)

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

So I've got this script here that moves the player by -1.25 when you click it but I want it to be continuously adding -1.25 until you release the button. Right now it only moves once when you click the button. My code:

```
var character : GameObject;
function OnMouseDown () {
    character.GetComponent(Animator).enabled = true;
    BlahBlah ();
}
function OnMouseUp () {
    character.GetComponent(Animator).enabled = false;
}

function BlahBlah () {
    character.transform.position.x = character.transform.position.x + -1.25;
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe have a Boolean that is set to true on mouse down and false on mouse up, then put the move in a while loop that checks this Boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're simply forgetting to work in the Update()

```
var character : GameObject;
function OnMouseDown () 
{
    character.GetComponent(Animator).enabled = true;
}

function OnMouseUp () 
{
    character.GetComponent(Animator).enabled = false;
}

function BlahBlah () 
{
    // I added time.deltaTime, since you'll be updating the value every "frame",
    // and deltaTime refers to how much time passed from the last frame
    // this makes your movement indipendent from the frame rate
    character.transform.position.x = character.transform.position.x  - (1.25* time.deltaTime);
}

// The standard Unity3D Update method runs every frame
void Update() 
{
    if (character.GetComponent(Animator).enabled)
    {
        BlahBlah ();
    }
}
```

What I did here is using Unity logic. Almost everything works in the Update() function, which gets called every frame. Note that frame rate can vary based on machine / complexity of scene, so make sure to use always Time.deltaTime when adding something related.

Another note for you: modifying the position directly won't make your object react to collisions ( so you'll be moving through objects, but you will still "trigger" the collision ). So, if you want to manage collision, remember to use physics!

Answer (score 0):

you can use **`Input.GetMouseButton`** because it registers **every frame** so when you **hold down** the mouse it gets it but because it checks every frame while the mouse is down so your object  will move **so fast** so you may want to add a **timer** that if the time is reached it moves so it moves a bit slower so we check if a specified amount of time that we set in **timeLeft** is **passed** and the mouse is **held down** then we move our object

```
   float timeLeft=0.5f; 

        void Update(){
          timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)){
                 if(timeLeft < 0)
                 {
                      BlahBlah ();
                 }
            }
        }

        void BlahBlah () {
            timeLeft=0.5f;
            character.transform.position.x = character.transform.position.x + -1.25;
        }
```

Comment: Don't you need a *time.deltatime on the end of that transform change?

Comment: he wants to moves his object in one frame i think , because his problem was not with moving it

Comment: Ah yeah just noticed he didn't have it either, still need it though!

Comment: it's a good practice to use time.deltaTime on movements in the update function, but it's not mandatory, it will work anyway, though the movement won't be the same on other devices

Answer (score 0):

As I remember onMouseDown fires every frame if you're holding the button, so you'll need to do the movement within that function, let me check one sec.